# How to add navigation bar in uitableview

Tags: uitableview

App based on Navigation base application.How to add Navigation bar in UItableview controller. Symptoms as a tableview controller(xib). I need to add in Navigation bar to symptoms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont add a navigationController to a tableViewController. its the other way around.
First add anavigationController and set its rootViewController as the tableViewControler.

Comment: your doing great job , i got now more confidence about your answer.  most of comments are add navigation bar  to  tableview, i know that not correct way to do, what i expect correct answer provided you . Thanks. i will put vote and accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

U can add it as you add the sub view to super view
-loadview:
navBar2=[[UINavigationBar alloc]init];
    [navBar2 sizeToFit];
    [self.view addSubview:navBar2];
//add button on the bar.
[navBar2 addSubview:button];

Comment: Your answer is correct , i put it vote for you. but actually what i need my project i got it , from Gopal Mallappan.

Answer (score -1):

maybe u can change in the xib, add a UIView below the TableView and then add the navigation bar as a subview of UIView

Comment: i see ur comment in Gopal's answer, I think you have to made a new xib and then connect this xib to the mainWindow.xib