# Beginner: How to add top bar with buttons on UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I'm new to iOS development, I just have `UITableViewController` in a storyboard. I would like to add a top bar to it with some buttons, how to do that?

Notice, I'm using UITabBar that is created by "Storyboard" and my ITableViewController is one item of the UITabBar.

Comment: If by 'top bar' you mean a navigation bar, see this article:
[Add nav bar to uitableview][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517164/how-to-add-navigation-bar-in-uitableview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create the `UITableViewController`, do the following:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableViewController];
```

and then instead of setting the table view controller as the view, set it to the navigation controller. Inside your table view controller, you can set the left and right buttons for the navigation bar to `UIBarButtonItem`s (ask me if you want to know how to do that).

Comment: Thanks ... the issue I don't inistiante the UITableViewController. i have the UITableViewController as item on UITabBar and the UITabBar is created by storyboard, so how could I tell the storyboard to use UINavigationController instead, and than  I create  UINavigationController with UITableviewcontroller ... i'm a bit confused.

Comment: Select your `UITableViewController` and go Editor > Embed In and choose a navigation controller. You should get something like this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-AdoptingStoryboards/Art/embeddedFirstViewController.png

Answer (score 3):

Select your UITableViewController and go Editor > Embed In and choose a navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

You might look at using the UINavigationController.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

If you do not want to use UINavigationController, then what you could do is create a view that has the "top bar" that you are looking for, then add the UITableViewController's view to your new UIView.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an `UIViewController`, not a `UITableViewController`, and then place the elements you desire however you want (in this case, a Table View and a UIToolbar).

Comment: Why not a UITableViewController? It's the same thing as UIViewController and already has table view

Comment: So could i just add a "top bar" to my UITableViewController?

Comment: You could, but it would get a bit hacky.

Comment: @beryllium i believe this is because a UITableViewController's View is by default the tableview